# Delete multiple table records using inner join

Tags: join

```
delete add_employee,job_title,admin
from add_employee
inner join job_title,admin
where 
admin.id=add_employee.emp_id and job_title.id='1';
```

output:
no records deleted....
Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.000 sec.

Comment: tag the DBMS(SQL Server/MySQL)

Comment: You'll have to run two separate queries to delete data.